# Provide a complete and accurate $\epsilon−N$ proof that the sequence $\{2+(−1)^n\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Provide a complete and accurate $\epsilon−N$ proof that the sequence $\{2+(−1)^n\}$
diverges.

My attempt:

Suppose that it converges, then there exists a real number L that it converges too

$\exists L \in \mathbb R, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N > 0$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > N$, then $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$

Let $\epsilon = 1$

Case when n is odd. If $n > N$, then $|1-L| < 1 \leftrightarrow 0 < L < 2$

Case when n is even. If $n > N$, then $|3 - L| < 1 \leftrightarrow 2 < L < 4$

Since the limit is not unique a contradiction. This series diverges.

Does this count as a complete $\epsilon - N$ proof?

Comment: "Since the limit is not unique a contradiction." You arrive at a contradiction, but this is an awkward way of saying it and not quite what the contradiction is

Comment: Since $L \in (0,2) \cap L \in (2,4)$ the limit is not unique as the definition states. Isn't that the contradiction?

Comment: No, the contradiction is that $L<2$ and $L>2$, which can't happen at the same time. This is essentially what you are trying to say. The way you said it is awkward is all.

Comment: Oh okay I see thank you

Comment: The proof is good.  But stylistically, it's generally considered better to use words rather than symbols.  You need to properly introduce the variable $N$: "Let $\epsilon = 1$.  Then by the definition of limit, there exists $N$ such that...."

Comment: The demonstration of the divergence (in this case, oscillating succession) is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_n=2+(-1)^n$.

Assume $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$.

Then for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N>0$ such that if $n\ge N$ then $\vert a_n-L\vert<\epsilon$.

Let $\epsilon=\min\left\{\left\vert\dfrac{1-L}{2}\right\vert,\left\vert\dfrac{3-L}{2}\right\vert\right\}$.

Then for any $N>0$ if $n>N$ either $\vert a_n-L\vert=\vert1-L\vert$ or $\vert a_n-L\vert=\vert3-L\vert$.

Thus, for $n>0$, $\vert a_n-L\vert>\epsilon$, which is a contradiction.

Thus the sequence $a_n$ diverges.